# Passing a string argument from HTML function to JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, arguments

I have the following function:

```
function myFunction(x, filename) {
    x.classList.toggle("checked");
    console.log("clicked"+filename);
}
```

It is being called as follows:

```
$('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"</a>" + "<i onclick=myFunction(this, obj[key][dd]) class='fa fa-star'></i><br></li>");
```

How can I modify the function call so that the value of the string stored in `obj[key][dd]` (`obj` is a 2D array where `key` and `dd` both are string values) is passed and the code is executed without errors?

Comment: What are obj, key and dd?  Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: obj is a 2D array where key and dd both are string values. Basically, I want to output the value stored in obj[key][dd].

Comment: Add quotation marks around your function: `onclick="myFunction(this, obj[key][dd])"`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I've found the solution, posted as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question by making the following changes:

```
var fname= key+"/"+obj[key][dd];
$('#bookmarks').append("<li><a target='_blank' href='/code/"+key+"/"+obj[key][dd]+"'>"+""+obj[key][dd]+"</a>" + "<i onclick=myFunction(this,\'"+fname +"\') class='fa fa-star'></i><br></li>");
```